# Assign Macro to button form control (with restrictions)

Tags: excel, button, vba

I'm looking to do the following:

Assign a macro to a form control button, but only let the user press this button once. Once the button is pressed once it shouldn't be possible to press it again. I'm trying to prevent accidental clicking of the button. The macro is sending a quantity to an accounting spreadsheet so I don't want to send anything twice by accident.

Comment: How do you want it to be, once per login, once per day. Best would be to set a counter and put an if condition to disable button if counter is more than 1...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the "Enabled" property, like:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    ...
End Sub
```